# didReceiveRemoteNotification function called twice

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, swift4

I am implementing push notification with my custom JSON payload using firebase cloud messaging, and it's running.

The problem I am facing right now is when I fire the notification,
`didRecieve` gets called and when user taps on the notification alert its gets called again.

I am navigating to other `viewcontroller` in `didRecieve`,
so in my case navigating to two times to the same vc.

How can I handle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you are implementing `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)`, this can be an expected behavior, as stated [here in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application#discussion):

> **Note**
>
> If the user opens your app from the system-displayed alert, the system
>   may call this method again when your app is about to enter the
>   foreground so that you can update your user interface and display information pertaining to the notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify if is in background:

```
if (application.applicationState == .background) {
      completionHandler(.noData)
      return
}
```

You can use the `willPresent` method to create a `alert` message.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (_ options: UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {}
```

You can disable in app notifications too as option.

And if you need in app notification AND touch option:

You can verify if the active controller already is the controller that you need.

Hope this help.